# Flutter app crashes on iPhone Xr (iOS 13) but never on Android (physical & emulator), older iPhone or iOS Simulator

Tags: flutter, ios13

Flutter app crashes randomly with "io.flutter.1.gpu (8): signal SIGABRT" on physical iPhone Xr (iOS 13) but never on Android, an older iPhone or iOS Simulator.

The crash happens when I navigate around in the app (on random screens).

The stacktrace is:

```
2020-02-05 18:46:41.225735+0100 Runner[30726:12308684]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist
2020-02-05 18:46:41.387987+0100 Runner[30726:12308605] Metal API Validation Enabled
2020-02-05 18:46:41.632361+0100 Runner[30726:12308605] Configuring the default Firebase app...
2020-02-05 18:46:41.632786+0100 Runner[30726:12308706] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:60139/AuOqNpK5gxY=/
2020-02-05 18:46:41.633329+0100 Runner[30726:12308688] 6.15.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000004] App with name __FIRAPP_DEFAULT does not exist.
2020-02-05 18:46:41.694350+0100 Runner[30726:12308693] 6.15.0 - [GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler][I-SWZ001011] App Delegate Proxy is disabled.
2020-02-05 18:46:41.694417+0100 Runner[30726:12308693] 6.15.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.60201000 started
2020-02-05 18:46:41.694445+0100 Runner[30726:12308693] 6.15.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2020-02-05 18:46:41.700683+0100 Runner[30726:12308710] 6.15.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS025036] App Delegate Proxy is disabled
2020-02-05 18:46:41.715063+0100 Runner[30726:12308605] Configured the default Firebase app __FIRAPP_DEFAULT.
2020-02-05 18:46:42.004500+0100 Runner[30726:12308684] 6.15.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled
validateFunctionArguments:3485: failed assertion `Vertex Function(#main): argument vertexBuffer.0[0] from buffer(15) with offset(32756) and length(32768) has space for 12 bytes, but argument has a length(60).'
```

flutter doctor -v

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-CH)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.7 at /Users/isaak/Developer/flutter
    • Framework revision 9f5ff2306b (11 days ago), 2020-01-26 22:38:26 -0800
    • Engine revision a67792536c
    • Dart version 2.7.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/isaak/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C504
    • CocoaPods version 1.8.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • My iPhone Xr • 00008020-001A49861A83002E            • ios • iOS 13.3
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max                        • A801E977-723C-44AB-8525-88B0DEAC4063 • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)

• No issues found!
```

I have no clue on how to fix this as I don't see a correlation from my flutter/dart code to the error.

I would greatly appreciate any possible explanation for a cause/fix or guidance on how to figure it out.

Comment: could you post your "flutter doctor -v"?

Answer (score 0):

They had said that iOS 13 have some changes in reading the file and logs of the application. The flutter team is working on that to make stable in future upgrades also.
The new update "Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.7" is way more stable. Even it throws 'n' number of error lines when working multiple api's it finishes the build and makes it responsive

try upgrading flutter using `Flutter Upgrade`